# The target type of this expression must be a functional interface for custom interface

Tags: java-8

I am trying to concat two string using Lambda expression. I have created functional interface StringFormatter which has format method which will take two strings as argument. it should return String.
The ans should be Returns "Lambda Expression" or Returns "Lambda – Expression" depending on lambda expression.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="Lambda";
        String s2="Expression";
        new Main().print(s1,s2);
    }

    public void print(String st1, String st2) {
       String result= (st1, st2) -> { return st1+" "+ st2;}; /*error- The target type of this expression must be a functional interface*/
       System.out.println(result);

    }
}
@java.lang.FunctionalInterface
interface StringFormatter {
    abstract String format(String s1, String s2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like that:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="Lambda";
        String s2="Expression";

        // format 1
        new Main().print(s1,s2, (str1, str2) -> str1 + " " + str2);

        // format 2
        new Main().print(s1,s2, (str1, str2) -> str1 + "-" + str2);

    }

    void print(String str1, String str2, StringFormatter formatter) {
        String result = formatter.format(str1, str2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}

@java.lang.FunctionalInterface
interface StringFormatter {
    String format(String s1, String s2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler solution:

```
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

// Define the printing function with this lambda
BinaryOperator<String> printFunction = (string1, string2) -> string1 + " " + string2;

// Call it and get the result
System.out.println(print(st1, st2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The BinaryOperator interface is available in *java.util.function package*. It can be used to perform a binary operation(eg: concatenation) on two values of T type and returns a T type result.

```
public void print(String st1, String st2) {
        BinaryOperator<String> concat = (a, b) -> a + " " + b;
        System.out.println(concat.apply(st1, st2));
}
```